# AWS S3 Bucket Policy to allow read/write access from aws machine learning

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, policy, bucket

Is it possible to create an S3 bucket policy that allows read and write access from aws machine learning ? I tried below bucket policy, but not work.

bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "machinelearning.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::cxra/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "machinelearning.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObjectAcl",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::cxra/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "machinelearning.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::cxra"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "machinelearning.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::cxra"
        }
    ]
}
```

[Error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKalg.png)

Comment: Change this arn:aws:s3:::cxra to arn:aws:s3:::cxra/* at 2 location in your resource and then check

Answer (score 0):

Double check your policy against [Granting Amazon ML Permissions to Output Predictions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/machine-learning/latest/dg/granting-amazon-ml-permissions-to-output-predictions-to-amazon-s3.html) to Amazon S3 and [Granting Amazon ML Permissions to Read Your Data from Amazon S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/machine-learning/latest/dg/granting-amazon-ml-permissions-to-read-your-data-from-amazon-s3.html)

As they are documented as two separate policies, I suggest you follow that, rather than joining the two policies in one single document.  It will be easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: Thanks. I will check more detail.

Comment: Solved this problem by check S3 url. Target file URL is wrong in the aws machine learning page, so i changed URL from "s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/cxra/ml1.csv" to "cxra/ml1.csv". Thanks your comment.